# Returning the 2nd positive integer in an array - functions and arrays

Tags: c, arrays, function

I'm trying to write a program that finds the second positive number in an array of integers. If there aren't two positive integers in the array, it should return `NOT_POSITIVE_ENOUGH`. However, my `array_second_positive()` function isn't working properly.

I'm also not allowed to change the array within the `array_second_positive()` function.

**The error I received:** dcc explanation: Ensure that your function will always return a value. If your function is not meant to return a value, try changing its return type to `void`.

```
#include <stdio.h>

#define NOT_POSITIVE_ENOUGH 0

// Returns the second positive number in the array.
// I'm having problems with this part function

int array_second_positive(int size, int array[size])
{

    int i = 0;
    int counter = 0;
    while (i < size)   // if array[size] > 0, then we count this via counter
    {
        if (array[i] > 0)
        {
            counter = i++;
        }
        // if we have reached 2 positive integers
        if (counter == 2)
        {
            return array[i];
        }
        else if ( counter < 2)     // if < 2 positive integers
        {
            return NOT_POSITIVE_ENOUGH;
        }
        i ++;
    }
}


// here is a function to test array_second_positive !

#define MAX_SIZE 100

int main(void)
{
    int size1 = 7;
    int array1[MAX_SIZE] = {3, -14, 15, 9, 2, 6, 5};

    int result1 = array_second_positive(size1, array1);
    if (result1 == NOT_POSITIVE_ENOUGH)
    {
        printf("array1 wasn't positive enough!\n");
    }
    else
    {
        printf("The second positive value from array1 is: %d\n", result1);
    }

    int size2 = 10;
    int array2[MAX_SIZE] = {-1, -2, -4, 8, -16, -32, -64, -128, -256, 512};

    int result2 = array_second_positive(size2, array2);
    if (result2 == NOT_POSITIVE_ENOUGH)
    {
        printf("array2 wasn't positive enough!\n");
    }
    else
    {
        printf("The second positive value from array2 is: %d\n", result2);
    }

    int size3 = 10;
    int array3[MAX_SIZE] = {-1, -3, -4, -8, -16, -33, -64, 138, -356, -513};

    int result3 = array_second_positive(size3, array3);
    if (result3 == NOT_POSITIVE_ENOUGH)
    {
        printf("array3 wasn't positive enough!\n");
    }
    else
    {
        printf("The second positive value from array3 is: %d\n", result3);
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Put your if outside the loop. It jumps out before it could ever find the the 2nd number.  so the "if (counter == 2)" should come after the loop.

Comment: remark: for loop is a clearer fit for loop with counters. If you looking for efficency: need some sort in some way.

Answer (score 0):

I think this modification should solve your problem

```
int array_second_positive(int size, int array[]) {
    
    int i = 0; 
    int counter = 0; 
    while (i < size) { 
        if (array[i] > 0) {
            counter++;
        }
        if (counter == 2) {
            return array[i];
        }
        i++; 
    }
    if(counter < 2) return NOT_POSITIVE_ENOUGH;
 }
```

Why was your code not working?

This was the error:

```
if (counter == 2) {
    return array[i];
} else if ( counter < 2) { // if < 2 positive integers 
    return NOT_POSITIVE_ENOUGH;
}
```

Suppose you have an array `{1,2,3}`, your function should return 2 but since you are assigning `counter=1` when processing `0th` index and then checking `counter < 2`, it'll immediately leave the loop and say you don't have enough positive integers.